# Scala - Traversing a ByteString Until Empty

Tags: scala, akka

**Is there a more concise and/or performant way to traverse the `message` than what I have here?**

```
    import akka.util.ByteString

    @throws[GarbledMessageException]
    def nextValue(message: ByteString) =

        message.indexOf(delimiter) match {

           case i if i >= 0 => message.splitAt(i)

           case _ => throw new GarbledMessageException("Delimiter Not Found")
       }


   @tailrec
   def processFields(message: ByteString): Unit = nextValue(message) match {

      case (_, ByteString.empty) => // Complete Parsing

      case (value, rest) =>
        // Do work with value

        // loop
        processFields(rest)
   }
```

A new ByteString is created for each split which hurts performance, but at least the underlying Buffer is not copied, only reference counted.

*Maybe it can be even better than that?*

Comment: I recommend putting @tailrec on the processFields  to have the compiler enforce tail recursion.  That'll prevent unintentionally blowing the stack.

Comment: I forgot to include that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on specifically what kind of work you are doing, but if you are looking for something more performant than splitting off ByteStrings, take a look at [ByteIterator](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/?_ga=1.72269712.2090780478.1386337281#akka.util.ByteIterator), which you can get by calling `iterator` on a ByteString.

A ByteIterator would allow you to go directly to primitive values (ints, floats, etc.) without having to split off new ByteStrings first.

Comment: Unfortunately my message data is ASCII encoded, so I cannot go straight to primitives unless I roll my own conversions. (Copy from Java std libs). Will give this approach some thought.

Comment: I don't know how your `nextValue` function is parsing the ByteString, but perhaps it could go directly to whatever kinds of objects your "work" uses, e.g. Strings, instead of splitting off ByteStrings first. For example  ByteString -> Array[Byte] -> String.    What kind of data does your work need?

Comment: In conjunction with that if might be easier to give advice if you posted the details of your `nextValue` function, since that is where you are splitting off ByteStrings.

Comment: I added the `nextValue` implementation.  From there I convert the `ByteString` to `Int`, `Double`, and `String`.  For now I took the easy way out and am using the `String` conversion step in between to make it work.  I am definitely interested in removing that step, maybe I can use `implicit` to help... (compiler optimizations)

Comment: You might be able to skip the new ByteString step once you find the delimiter, but I actually don't see much value in doing that, I think it is already fairly optimal performance-wise. I also coded up a non-recursive version using a `Stream`, but unfortunately it doesn't end up being more concise or performant—just an alternative. I can post it if you are interested.

Comment: I think your proposed usage of `ByteIterator` may be the key to getting the best performance and removing the verbose recursion.